# TeXstudio: content-assistant popup window is unreadable

Tags: latex

I would like to use this program but I do not know how to display context-sensitive help (see figure below) without a black background. I use Ubuntu 12.10 and I don't know what other information might be helpful to solve this problem. Thus, the program behaves since installation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by changing the style.
Go to **Options** > **Configure TexStudio** > **General**.
Under **Style** try something besides GTK+ or default. I had success with everything but these two.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this by unchecking "Ignore most system colors" on this option tab (advanced options have to be enabled to see it).