# Ubuntu 14.04 Help mouse hover is black stripe!

Tags: 14.04, gnome, mouse, eclipse

I have ubuntu 14.04 installed in my system. Whenever I open the browser or an application and try to hover the mouse over any links, I get a black strip. For example, when I bring my mouse on any of the links, I will not see the description of the link, I get a black stripe. I use eclipse extensively, and when I get any error I don't see any help that usually is seen by hovering the mouse over the error line, instead I see the black line. I also cannot capture this weird movement in the screenshot. I cannot open GNOME color manager also to make any changes.

Can anyone help me here? It is really very important for me and I am not getting any links from Google on this. Any help from Ubunut gurus will make my project go smoothly.

Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: EDIT : I can see similar kind of black stripe for all the applications on Ubuntu 14.04. Here is the link of the screenshot which is similar to the issue I am facing : : http://askubuntu.com/questions/250912/texstudio-content-assistant-popup-window-is-unreadable

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.